# pyaudio generating blank .wav files

Tags: pyaudio

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
# close PyAudio (7)
p.terminate()
```

The `output.wav` file is generated successfully wih a size of approx. 881KB. However, when I play it, it's blank.

Currently, I'm trying to record audio through the built in microphone of my MacBook Pro.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this has to do something with the OS. 
I tried executing the same thing on an Ubuntu machine and it worked. On macOS Catalina, it produced blank files.

I'll need to dig a little deeper on macOS to find out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too and it will work if you grant Terminal access to your microphone!

If Terminal isn't showing up in the System Preferences list for microphone permissions and it hasn't requested permission (a problem on Mojave/Catalina), open it by:

```
open /System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
```

Then run a program that uses the mic e.g.

```
sox -d -d
```

(Note: You will need to install SoX. This specific command will let you hear your mic input. You could also use pyaudio, FFmpeg, ecasound etc.)

That should trigger it to request. If that didn't work try running the command on a different command line e.g. iTerm2. This is a problem and solution very similar to the one for Audacity on Catalina. I'm not sure what the exact cause is though.